# Simplifying up/down vote code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this working JavaScript (example is [here][1]), which should work the same as on the Stack Exchange network.

How can I simplify it a bit?

```
function yellow() {
    return 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
}


$(function() {
    $(".post-upvote").click(function() {
      //  ajax(url + "upvote/" + $(this).attr('data-postid'), false, false);

        if ($(this).parent().children('.post-downvote').css('background-color') == yellow()) { // user upvoted so let's delete upvote
            $(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text(parseInt($(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text()) + parseInt(1));
        }
        $(this).parent().children('.post-downvote').css('background-color', 'white');

        if ($(this).css('background-color') == yellow()) { // if it's yellow, user is canceling his downvote
            $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
            $(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text(parseInt($(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text()) - parseInt(1));
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
            $(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text(parseInt($(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text()) + parseInt(1));
        }
    });
    $(".post-downvote").click(function() {
       // ajax(url + "downvote/" + $(this).attr('data-postid'), false, false);

        if ($(this).parent().children('.post-upvote').css('background-color') == yellow()) { // user upvoted so let's delete upvote
            $(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text(parseInt($(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text()) - parseInt(1));
        }

        $(this).parent().children('.post-upvote').css('background-color', 'white');

        if ($(this).css('background-color') == yellow()) { // if it's yellow, user is canceling his downvote
            $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
            $(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text(parseInt($(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text()) + parseInt(1));
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
            $(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text(parseInt($(this).parent().children('.post-votes').text()) - parseInt(1));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of antipatterns like

```
parseInt(1)
```

Just say `1` instead.

Factor out common code like

```
$(this).parent().children('.post-votes')
```

and

```
$(this).css('background-color')
```

into variables.

Combine the two handlers thus

```
function vote(isUpvote) {
    var control = $(this);
    var otherControl = control.parent().children(
        isUpvote ? ".post-downvote" : ".post-upvote");
    var postVotes = control.parent().children(".post-votes");
    var ajaxHandler = isUpvote ? "upvote/" : "downvote/";

    // ajax(url + ajaxHandler + control.attr('data-postid'), false, false);

    // user voted so let's delete the other control
    if (otherControl.css("background-color") == yellow()) {
        postVotes.text(+(postVotes.text()) + 1);
    }
    control.parent().children(otherId).css("background-color", "white");

    // if it's yellow, user is cancelling their vote
    if (control.css("background-color") == yellow()) {
        control.css("background-color", "white");
        postVotes.text(+(postVotes.text()) - 1);
    } else {
        control.css("background-color", "yellow");
        postVotes.text(+(postVotes.text()) + 1);
    }
}

$(".post-upvote"  ).click(function() { vote.call(this, true); });
$(".post-downvote").click(function() { vote.call(this, false); });
```

Comment: I wasn't able to do `something + 1` because it made `12` from `1`

Comment: @genesis, That happens when `something` is not a number because then `+` does string concatenation instead of addition.  `parseInt(something, 10) + 1` is fine as is `(+something) + 1` because they both cause the `something` to be coerced to a number.  The `parseInt(1)` does not since `1` is already a number.

Comment: ok so I can "convert" string to number with (+var) + 1 ?

Comment: @genesis, Yes, assuming "var" is the name of a variable instead of the keyword.  Try running `+"42" + 1 === 43` in the [squarefree shell](http://squarefree.com/shell/shell.html).

Comment: and about your last snippet, I am not 100% how should I include it effectively. Could you add some more please?

Comment: I still didn't get those two last lines. Why do you pass "this" as a parameter, and not true and in that second false?

Comment: @genesis, see the docs on [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call): Calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.